# Entity Framework with Sybase SQL Anywhere 16 crashes Visual Studio

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, ef-database-first, sqlanywhere

I am trying to use Entity Framework with Sybase SQL Anywhere 16 and database first. I have successfully integrated SQL Anywhere into Visual Studio over SetupVSPackage. I also have added the correct data provider like this:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere" 
                  type="iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAProviderServices, iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.EF6, Version=16.0.0.21274, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f222fc4333e0d400" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

But now I have the problem that when I try to add a data model, nothing happens, no files were added. If I start Visual Studio with administration access, it simply crashes.

Did anyone get SQL Anywhere 16 working with Entity Framework 6 database first?

**Edit**

If I start visual studio with devenv.exe /log , the created log file does not contains any error messages. Even the windows eventlog does not contain any error messages.

Thank you!

Comment: how is it crashing? what errors have you seen?

Comment: No error, it quits silent

Comment: look in the usual logging places.

Comment: Is the SQLAnywhere database you're trying to model v16 as well?